# MarketingCloud Cordova plugin not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, cordova, push-notification

I have set up the Cordova plugin for Marketing Cloud but in Chrome Debugger console for my Android device, I can't see any call to Marketing Cloud servers.

I have set the `app_id`, the `access_token`, the `tenant_specific_endpoint` and the `notification_small_icon`.

I call the methods `MCCordovaPlugin.enablePush()` and `MCCordovaPlugin.setContactKey()` with the appropriate contactKey, and no error nor warning appear in JS console.

My cordova-android version is 7.1.0 and the plugin version is 6.2.2.

What could I have forgotten?

Comment: Turn on logging https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin#mccordovapluginenableverboseloggingsuccesscallback-errorcallback then post more details.

Comment: I think the reason this post was closed is it lacks a code example to demonstrate/reproduce the problem. Would it be possible to **[edit]** your post to include at least a pseudo-code version of what you are doing?